# data post to server error using GSM module bby Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

+HTTPACTION:1,302,213

what is the solution for this error or what does this error perfectly menas

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Response 302 means "FOUND" which means you are being redirected to another address.  You need to read the full response, extract the URL they're redirecting you to (Labelled as `Location: hxxp://www.someurl`,) then request that address instead.

If you're getting this for every URL, it may be that your SIM has not been activated for Data.

Possible Duplicate of this [Arduino GSM Shield WebClient 302](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423713/arduino-gsm-shield-webclient-302)